# Refresh Bootstrap-table after adding a new row

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I have applied bootstrap table on a table with detailView enabled

```
$("table#orders").bootstrapTable({detailView: true});
```

Its working fine and showing the Plus(+) icon/button for detail view.
Now I am dynamically adding a new row to this table

```
$('table#orders').append('<tr><td>Some Date</td></tr>');
```

After replacing the row it doesn't show the detail view icon/button for the newly added row

After trying the refresh, its showing the detail view icon but the content of newly added row are not displayed instead showing the old row

```
$('table#orders').bootstrapTable('refresh');
```

Any workaround on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`Bootstrap-Table` as an API to append row -

$('#table').bootstrapTable('append',{ key: 'Data'});

Working Demo -

```js
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
  detailView: true,
  detailFormatter: detailFormatter
});
$('#add').click(() => {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable('append', {
    0: 'Some Date'
  });
});

function detailFormatter(index, row) {
  return row[0];
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/multiple-select@1.5.2/dist/multiple-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Bootstrap-table</h3>
  <button id="add">
  Add
  </button>
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>First</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Second</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/multiple-select@1.5.2/dist/multiple-select.min.js"></script>
```